# Since which version is this method implemented?

Tags: python

Since which version is the `FileObject.truncate()` method implemented in Python? I need the exact version number so that I can specify on my GitHub account from when you can use the program.

Comment: Could you tell us the package from which it comes ?

Comment: It's a built-in function.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_truncate.asp

Comment: Ah, that's the problem... don't use w3schools to learn _anything_, especially Python. There's [an official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html) that will be much higher quality.

Comment: Hum, the name isn't "FileObject" so ^^ but i get it

Comment: W3Schools is terrible. Don't use it. (Also, that name is blatantly pretending to be associated with W3C, the World Wide Web Consortium, so they look more official, but there is no affiliation whatsoever.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking about the `.truncate()` method of Python file objects, it's been there "forever". The oldest docs python.org keeps around are for version 1.4, and you can see `.truncate()` [documented in 1.4 here](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/lib/node22.html#SECTION00317800000000000000).

Otherwise I don't know what you could mean by `FileObject` (there's nothing of that name in the CPython distribution).